# jQuery not working in IE when selecting an item in dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have a dropdown that shows countries. When the user selects United States or Canada, then another drop drop will appear. Everything works with Firefox, but not with Internet Explorer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.CountriesDropDown').change(changeAddressOptions);
   // alert('loaded');
    // call change event in case value was cached from reset
});

function changeAddressOptions(){
    // this is drop down
    var jsThis = $(this);
    var selectedVal = jsThis.val();

    var targetElementWrapper = jsThis.parents('li:first').siblings('.addressContentsWrapper');
    var elementToPopulate = targetElementWrapper.children('.addressContents');

    if (selectedVal == null || selectedVal == '') {
        targetElementWrapper.fadeOut();
        elementToPopulate.empty();
    }
    else {
        var loadingImage = jsThis.siblings('.loadingImage');
        loadingImage.show();
        var bindingPrefix = extractBindingPrefix(jsThis);
        if (selectedVal == 'US') {
            var elementUrl = '/AddressInfo.aspx/UsAddressInfo/?bindingPrefix=' + bindingPrefix;
        }
        else if (selectedVal == 'CA') {
        var elementUrl = '/AddressInfo.aspx/CanadaAddressInfo/?bindingPrefix=' + bindingPrefix;
        }
        else {
            var elementUrl = '/AddressInfo.aspx/InternationalAddressInfo/?bindingPrefix=' + bindingPrefix;
        }
        targetElementWrapper.hide();
        elementToPopulate.empty();
        $(elementToPopulate).load(elementUrl, countryLoadComplete);
    }
}

function countryLoadComplete() {
    var wrapper = $(this).parents('.addressContentsWrapper:first');
    $(wrapper).fadeIn('fast', hideLoadingImage);
}

function hideLoadingImage() {
    var loadingImage = $(this).siblings().find('.loadingImage');
    loadingImage.hide();
}

function extractBindingPrefix(element) {
    // hack - grab binding prefix from neighboring labe, since lastIndexOf never works;
    var bindingPrefixHolder;
    var bindingPrefix;
    bindingPrefixHolder = $(element).siblings('.bindingPrefix');
  ///  var lastPeriod = elementName.indexOf('.', 0);
   // if (lastPeriod = -1)
   //     bindingPrefix = '';
    //else {
    //    bindingPrefix = elementName.substring(0, lastPeriod);
   // }

    bindingPrefix = bindingPrefixHolder.html();
    return bindingPrefix;
}
```

Comment: Which version(s) of IE have you tried? Compatibility mode on/off?

Comment: Press F12 to launch Developer Tools in IE8, then debug you script. For earlier IE versions you can install the tools separately, as far as I remember.

Comment: Also, Visual Studio can debug javascript code, when it runs webapp in IE.

Comment: I am running IE 8, 6 and 7. All the all dont work.

Comment: Where abouts is it not working? Is it loading the data, adding the elements or even the animation (could be something screws up and it doesn't show the fields)?

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap you jQuery objects in $() everytime you use a jQuery function:

```
var jsThis = $(this);
var selectedVal = jsThis.val();
```

Should be

```
var jsThis = $(this);
var selectedVal = $(jsThis).val();
```

This needs to be fixed in numerous places in your script.

Comment: It is still not working. This what I have now. I have made the change as you have sugested. Please keep in mind that I am new to jquery. Thanks

Comment: I am also thinking that it has something do with the timingout. there is a disscustion... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459224/jquery-animate-and-browser-performance

Comment: I am just not that familiar with jquery.