# Frame rate of jQuery animation

Tags: jquery

I know that jQuery animations have a default frame rate. However, my animations look very different from computer to computer, some are smoother than others.

Is there a way to determine the actual outputted frame rate of jQuery animations?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459224/jquery-animate-and-browser-performance

Comment: I always understood that this depended on the speed of the individual computer and efficiency of the browser, which aren't things that jQuery can actually measure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default frame rate is [77fps](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-jquery-uses-77-fps-by-default-in-animation), however, in different browsers, this can vary; "[Chrome's fastest possible interval is about 10ms [while a]ll other browsers "sample" at about 20-30ms.](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#comment-50886341)".  There are a lot of potential sources of animation lag from system to system and browser to browser, and there are [several(1)](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) [different(2)](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/framerate-control-system-for-javascript/) [projects(3)](http://www.kaizou.org/2011/06/effectively-measuring-browser-framerate-using-css/) feeling out ways to help us develop with timing in mind.  For now, you could try standardizing your frame rate using [a plugin](http://skookum.com/blog/making-smoother-animations-with-jquery/) and see if that helps you time your animations more easily, or [tweak it manually](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/).